# how can I use csv tools for zip text file?

Tags: python

update-my file.txt.zp is tab delimited and looks kind of like this :
[file.txt.zp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqgp4.jpg)
I want to split the first col by : _ /

---

original post:
I have a very large zipped tab delimited file.
I want to open it, scan it one row at a time, split some of the col, and write it to a new file.
I got various errors (every time I fix one another pops)
This is my code:

```
import csv
import re
import gzip

f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz')
original = f.readlines()
f.close()

original_l = csv.reader(original)
for row in original_l:
    file_l = re.split('_|:|/',row)
    with open ('newfile.gz', 'w', newline='') as final:
        finalfile = csv.writer(final,delimiter = ' ')
        finalfile.writerow(file_l)
```

Thanks!

for this code i got the error:

```
for row in original_l:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

so based on what I found here I added this after f.close():

```
original = original.decode('utf8')
```

and then got the error:

```
original = original.decode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: `(every time I fix one another pops)` That's the daily life of a programmer.

Comment: What are the current error messages? [Edit] them into the question along with what you have tried in terms of resolving.

Comment: Besides adding the error messages, also please consider adding a small example demonstrating what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

This code should produce the output that you're after.

```
import csv
import gzip
import re

with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', mode='rt') as f, \
        open('newfile.gz', 'w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter=' ')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    _ = next(reader)        # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(re.split(r'_|:|/', row[0]))
```

**Update**

Open the gzip file in text mode because `str` objects are required by the CSV module in Python 3.

```
f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rt')
```

Also specify the delimiter when creating the `csv.reader`.

```
original_l = csv.reader(original, delimiter='\t')
```

This will get you past the first hurdle.

Now you need to explain what the data is, which columns you wish to extract, and what the output should look like.

Original answer follows...

---

One obvious problem is that the output file is constantly being overwritten by the next row of input. This is because the output file is opened in (over)write mode (`'w`` ) once per row.

It would be better to open the output file once outside of the loop.

Also, the CSV file delimiter is not specified when creating the reader. You said that the file is tab delimited so specify that:

```
original_l = csv.reader(original, delimiter='\t')
```

On the other hand, your code attempts to split each row using other delimiters, however, the rows coming from the `csv.reader` are represented as a list, not a string as the `re.split()` code would require.

Another problem is that the output file is not zipped as the name suggests.

Comment: Thanks, It's all new to me so I'm struggling with the basics. For now it doesn't even get to this part of the code. The errors refer to the first lines as you can see in my edited question.

Comment: (On the other hand, your code attempts to split each row using other delimiters, however, the rows coming from the csv.reader are represented as a list, not a string as the re.split() code would require.) how can I convert the list to a string or use split on a list?

Comment: @Lala: What is the delimiter in your CSV file? Perhaps you could add a _small_ uncompressed sample of the input file that you are processing.

Comment: @Lala: updated answer with some details to help you get past the first issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I uploaded a few raws from the file as a jpeg. it is tab delimited.